# Getting an empty array instead of a randomly generated array of integers

Tags: java, arrays, class

I'm new to Java, and this is part of my assignments for school. I keep getting the following output and I can't figure out why:

```
[]
```

I have to create a class called RandomArray, which takes a length(n) and fills an array (of length n) with random numbers from 0 to array's length. Class should also contain methods for average, min, and max values.

Here's the class I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class RandomArray {

private int length;
int randomNum = 0;

public void setLength(int length) 
{
    this.length=length;
}

//creating array of specified length
int[]a=new int [length];

public void fill() // populate array with random numbers
{
    for (int i=0;i<a.length; i++)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt(a.length);
        a[i]=randomNum;
    }
}

public int maximum() 
{
    int max=1;
    for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++)
    {
        if(a[j]>max)
            max=a[j];
    }
    return max; 
}

public int minimum () 
{
    int min = 0;
    for (int k=0; k<a.length; k++)
    {
        if(a[k]<min)
        min=a[k];
    }

    return min; 
}

public float average() 
{
    float sum=0;
    float avg;
    for (int l=0; l<a.length; l++)
    {
        sum=sum+a[l];
    }
    avg=(float)(sum/a.length);
    return avg; 
}

public String toString() {
    return Arrays.toString(a);
}
}
```

And here's the driver class:

```
public class RandomArrayDriver {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        RandomArray arr1=new RandomArray ();
        arr1.setLength(8);
        arr1.fill();

        System.out.println(arr1);
        arr1.average();
        arr1.minimum();
        arr1.maximum();
    }
}
```

I can't figure it out. I don't know if it's the fill() method or something else.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array is always initialized with size zero. Here's how it works:

When an instance of `RandomArray` is created, it will have `int length` with a default value of 0, then it will initialize the array, specifically here:

```
int[]a=new int [length];
```

Since `length` is zero, then line above is the same as:

```
int[]a=new int [0];
```

And you never re assign the array with a new value.

It will be better to set the length of the array on the constructor and that should remain unchanged:

```
public class RandomArray {

    private int length;
    int randomNum = 0;

    /*
    public void setLength(int length) {
        this.length=length;
    }
    */

    //creating array of specified length
    int[]a;//=new int [length];

    public RandomArray(int length) {
        this.length = length;
        a = new int[length];
    }
    //rest of the code...
}
```

If you want to have the array with *dynamic* length, then you should do some changes to your `setLength` method to support *remembering* the previous elements:

```
public void setLength(int length) {
    this.length = length;
    int[] newArray = new int[length];
    int backupSize = a.length > this.length? this.length : a.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < backupSize; i++) {
        newArray[i] = a[i];
    }
    a = newArray;
}
```

Comment: I would say that there is no necessity for the `length` field

Answer (score 1):

```
private int length;
int[]a;
public void setLength(int length)
{
    this.length=length;
    a = new int [length];
}
```

Have a declaration and initialize the array `a` in the constructor. 
You were creating an array of length zero every time.

Comment: Problem with this approach is that every time you change the length, a new array is created and old elements are *forgotten*.

Comment: Probably that is his requirement, else he would have a constructor with the length of the array as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling setLength(), it's not modifying your array in any way. You can modify the same method like this and you'll get the desired answer:

```
public void setLength(int length) {
    a = new int [length];
}
```